# Expanding out function - why is it the right strategy for this problem?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

In Spivaks Calculus there is problem 8 in chapter 3:

> For which numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ will the function
>   $$
>   f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx + d}
> $$
>   satisfy $f(f(x)) = x$ for all $x$?

Now, [the solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/2zqeg6/spivak_calculus_chapter_3_problem_8_find_values/) I found suggests to expand out $f(f(x))$ and then simplify and arrive at the solution.

> **8.** If
>   $$
>     x
>   = f(f(x))
>   = \frac{a \left( \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \right) + b}
>          {c \left( \frac{ax+b}{cx+d} \right) + d}
> $$
>   for all $x$ then
>   $$
>   (ac+cd)x^2 + (d^2 - a^2)x - ab - bd = 0
>   \qquad
>   \text{for all $x$}.
> $$
>
> (Original image [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/2zqeg6/spivak_calculus_chapter_3_problem_8_find_values/).)

I understand how generally expanding out works, but:

- I wonder why it makes sense to do that for this problem.
- What the solution in the end tells me/how it helps me to find numbers $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at in your first question. In what way might this calculation be nonsensical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It's sensible to do this because you're given information about how the composition $(f\circ f)(x) = f\big(f(x)\big)$ should be defined, namely that
   $$
   f\big(f(x)\big) = x.
   $$
   Since you're given that $f(x)$ has the fractional form, you substitute it into itself for the composition and rearrange to get the equation that is quadratic in $x$. The reason for doing so is answered next.
2. You have a quadratic in $x$ that equals zero, namely the quadratic
   $$
   (ac + cd)x^{2} + (d^{2} - a^{2})x -(ab + bd) = 0.
   $$
   For this to be true *for every value of $x$*, I hope that you can see that we must have
   $$
   ac + cd = 0,\qquad d^{2} - a^{2} = 0,\qquad ab + bd = 0.
   $$
   These can be rewritten as
   $$
   c(a + d) = 0,\qquad (d - a)(d + a) = 0,\qquad b(a + d) = 0.
   $$
   Thus

   1. the first equation is zero if either $c = 0$ or $a = -d$;
   2. the second equation is zero if either $a = d$ or $a = -d$;
   3. the third equation is zero if either $b = 0$ or $a = -d$.

This actually gives two nice cases to consider. First, if $a = -d$ then all equations are satisfied so that
$$
f(x) = \frac{ax + b}{cx - a}.
$$
You should check that $(f\circ f)(x) = f\big(f(x)\big) = x$ for this $f$.

The second case is to suppose that $a = d$ so that $c = 0$ and $b = 0$. This gives
$$
f(x) = \frac{ax}{a} = x,
$$
which clearly satisfies $(f\circ f)(x) = f\big(f(x)\big) = x$.

We note that if both $a = d$ and $a = -d$ are satisfied, then $a = d = 0$ so that
$$
f(x) = \frac{b}{cx}.
$$
This also satisfies $(f\circ f)(x) = f\big(f(x)\big) = x$ which you should check. This is just a special case of the first case.

Comment: Thanks! The first coefficient in the resulting quadratic should be $(ac+cd)$ I think.

Comment: If we have $ac+cd=0$ and $d^2-a^2=0$ and $ab+bd=0$ then $d^2=a^2$ so $d=a$. From there we can find that $ac+cd=0$ and cancelling out $a, d$ we find $c+c=0$ so $c=-c$? That somehow doesn't make sense to me. Can you clarify some more?

Comment: Note that $c = -c \iff c = 0$, which is precisely the case. I will edit my answer some more so that you can see how one should carefully deal with these.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation! It touched on a lot of topics which I still need to learn.